# ASP.NET MVC 4 Architecture Design Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have to rebuild an existing asp.net application using asp.net mvc 4 and I'm facing a design issue as I'm not confident enough with my mvc skills yet.

The existing application is for subscribing to insurance premium. The input sceen has controls for filling info about:

- client details
- risk detail: the risk can be of different types (Car, Truck) and the controls are dynamic. We have inheritance here with a RiskBase class, then RiskCar and RiskTruck.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how this would map to the MVC architecture.

Let's say I have a Contract business object as follow:

Contract{

- Client theClient
- RiskCar  theRisk
  }

Should I create one ViewModel for the entire page (View) ? I'd be tempted to create a partial View for the Risk but then it would have to be a different View for each type of Risk. How can I manage that ?  What would the ViewModel looks like for the parent View ?

Comment: Have you completed any of the mvc tutorials? Sometimes it just takes a little bit more practice to understand how to design

Comment: I have indeed. But I didn't find any tutorials dealing with inheritance. That's really my problem here. How do I create an inheritance of Views (RiskCarView, RiskTruckView) based on the type of RiskViewModel ?

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: This is a vague question.  Start writing some code and come back when you get stuck.  As it is, you are unlikely to get many meaningful answers.